# Laravel 5.2 - Output to a view

Tags: output, laravel-5

I have a simple method that passes info to a view:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $thissite = DB::table('this_site')->where('id',1)->get();
    $slider1 = DB::table('front_sliders')->where('active',1)->take(10)->get();
   return view('index')->with('slider1',$slider1)->with('site', $thissite );
});
```

All the data is passed OK and the $thissite is just one record, with one of the fields being called headline.

My problem is outputting this single variable along the lines of:

```
 <h1><strong>{{ headline }}</strong></h1>
```

I have tried many variations on this but I am not getting anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

So `headline` is a column in `this_site`? If so then the this should work:

```
<h1><strong>{{ $site->headline }}</strong></h1>
```

Comment: I have tried this and got Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\Laravel\freshskymedia\resources\views\master\frontend.blade.php). Frontend.php is the master layout which index extends

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
 <h1><strong>{{ $site[0]->headline }}</strong></h1>
```